# Kendall’s tau-b version calculation steps with tied ranks

Tags: python, scipy, kendall-tau, ties

I am trying to calculate Kendall’s tau coefficient for example given by [Scipy in python](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kendalltau.html). It is for tied ranks with tau-b version. The tau should be -0.47140452079103173 but I get a different result. I use formulas in "Handbook of Parametric and Nonparametric. Statistical Procedures. David J. Sheskin. Chapman & Hall/CRC." page 900.

$$x = [12, 2, 1, 12, 2]$$
$$y = [1, 4, 7, 1, 0]$$

rank the data:
$$rank x = [4.5, 2.5, 1, 4.5, 2.5]$$
$$rank y = [2.5, 4, 5, 2.5, 1]$$

dimensions: $n=5, m=2 $
$$rank x+rank y = [7, 6.5, 6, 7, 3.5]$$ $$T=7+6.5+6+7+3.5=30$$
$$U=7^2+6.5^2+6^2+7^2+3.5^2=188.5$$

calculate the tie correlation(${\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^m}{\displaystyle\sum_{a=1}^s}(t^3-t)$):

in x there are 2 tied groups each with 2 members: $(2^3-2)+(2^3-2)=12$

in y there is 1 tied group with 2 members: $(2^3-2)= 6$

total tie correlations: $12+6=18$

$$W=\frac{12U-3m^2n(n+1)^2}{m^2n(n^2-1)-m{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^m}{\displaystyle\sum_{a=1}^s}(t^3-t)}=\frac{12(188.5)-3\times 2^2\times 5(5+1)^2}{2^2\times5(5^2-1)-2(18)}=0.22973$$

Sorry for the low-quality question. there are not many numeric questions for tau-b. I hope this question can be helpful also for others who review python's example.

Comment: Scipy may use an adjusted algorithm for the calculation. Have you taken a look at the code?

Comment: You say you used the " *formulas in "Handbook of Parametric and Nonparametric.* ". Are these all listed out? Otherwise, readers may not know which formulas/algorithms you are referring to.

Comment: Also, there appear to be multiple algorithms for Kendall's tau: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient. It'll be useful to know which Scipy is using.

Comment: @jon the formula is the one written in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula you are using is calculating [Kendall's W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall's_W), also known as Kendall's coefficient of concordance. Kendall's W not the same as Kendall's tau-b.

To calculate the Kendall tau-b for the given data set, you can use the formula in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient#Tau-b). I count $n_0=10$, $n_1=2$, $n_2=1$, $n_c=2$, $n_d=6$, so that
$$
\tau_B=\frac{ 2-6}{\sqrt{(10-2)(10-1)}}=-\frac4{\sqrt{72}}=-.4714045.
$$

EDIT: How to calculate $n_1$? We see that $x$ has two groups of ties, namely $\{2,2\}$ and $\{12,12\}$, each with two ties per group, so $t_1=2$ and $t_2=2$ and $$n_1:=\frac12\sum_it_i(t_i-1)=\frac12(2\cdot1)+\frac12(2\cdot1)=2.$$  As for $n_2$, we see that $y$ has one group of ties, namely $\{1,1\}$, so $u_1=2$ and $$n_2:=\frac12\sum_ju_j(u_j-1)=\frac12(2\cdot1)=1.$$

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will take a look and then accept it. about the calculation of U, I used ranks not vectors itself.

Comment: @Woeitg You are right about the ranks. I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: well, actually I did that mistake in the first place and then modify the question. maybe you saw it before modification. Now I add more modification to clarify it.

Comment: @Woeitg Right, I recall you got a value of $W$ that was much higher than 1.

Comment: Can you add steps for calculating n1 and n2? number of ties in x is 2 (there are two group of similar values) and 1 (there is one group of similar value). feed it in formula gives n1=(2(2-1)/2)+(2(2-1)/2+0+(2(2-1)/2)+(2(2-1)/2=4

Comment: very good answer, tnx

Comment: @Woeitg The formula for $n_1$ has only two terms, one per group, and the formula for $n_2$ has one term, one per group.

Comment: I think nc=6 and nd=2, take a look:http://i.imgur.com/bfbyVAr.png and the tau with  nc=6 and nd=2 is correct

Comment: @Woeitg You are right; I have corrected the calculation.